# How to pass flag to gcc in Python setup.py script?

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-api

I'm writing a Python extension in C that requires the CoreFoundation framework (among other things). This compiles fine with:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -framework CoreFoundation -framework Python
```

("-framework" is an Apple-only gcc extension, but that's okay because I'm using their specific framework anyway)

How do I tell setup.py to pass this flag to gcc?

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work (it compiles, but then complains of undefined symbols when I try to run it):

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      author='Me',
      ext_modules=[Extension('foo',
                             ['foo.c'],
                             extra_compile_args=['-framework CoreFoundation'])])
```

**Edit:**

This appears to work:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      author='Me',
      ext_modules=[Extension('foo',
                             ['foo.c'],
                             extra_link_args=['-framework', 'CoreFoundation'])])
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe you need to set `extra_link_args`, too? `extra_compile_args` is used when compiling the source code, `extra_link_args` when linking the result.

Comment: Sorry; after deleting the "build" directory and re-building it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: After finding this I found the list of available arguments helpful.  http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=extension#distutils.core.Extension  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.