# Error when importing module, dlopen(): Symbol not found

Tags: python, dlopen

I have written a python extension in C (using cython, actually, though that's beside the point) which uses the AudioUnit framework in Mac OSX.  The module builds correctly, but when I try to import it from the python command line, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(myproject/audiomodule.so, 2): Symbol not found: _AudioUnitSetProperty
  Referenced from: /Views/python/lib/python3.1/site-packages/myproject/audiomodule.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

How do I tell python that it needs to use the AudioUnit framework when loading this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah, as was written in [this answer regarding a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676384/how-to-pass-flag-to-gcc-in-python-setup-py-script), the key was to pass the `-framework` and `AudioUnit` arguments as two separate tuple items.  Furthermore, my platform detection was incorrect, so these flags were not being applied correctly during the build.