# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing pylibrabbitmq

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am installing pylibrabbitmq on Ubuntu. But getting the error. I have downloaded pylibrabbitmq from Git Hub. And i'm doing 'python setup.py install'. But getting the following error.

Here is the log,

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pylibrabbitmq.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pylibrabbitmq.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pylibrabbitmq.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
file pylibrabbitmq.py (for module pylibrabbitmq) not found
reading manifest file 'pylibrabbitmq.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.o'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.so'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.dylib'
writing manifest file 'pylibrabbitmq.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
file pylibrabbitmq.py (for module pylibrabbitmq) not found
file pylibrabbitmq.py (for module pylibrabbitmq) not found
running build_ext
building '_pyrabbitmq' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.h:16,
                 from pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.c:7:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1161:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:215:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.c:7:0:
pylibrabbitmq/_rabbitmqmodule.h:18:18: fatal error: amqp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `amqp.h` (the C header file from librabbitmq, the libarary pylibrabbitmq relies upon).

Either install that file [manually](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c), or install the [package that contains it](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=amqp.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any), [librabbitmq-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/librabbitmq-dev).

Comment: It is in /tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq.

Comment: That directory is not in the default [header search path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html). Move it one of the default locations or add `-I/tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq` to the gcc invocation to add it to the search path.

Comment: Can you plz tell how can I add -I/tmp/src/rabbit/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq to the gcc invocation???

Comment: It will be way easier just to install it in a default location. But if you insist, set `extra_compile_args` in `setup.py`, like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676384/how-to-pass-flag-to-gcc-in-python-setup-py-script). Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pombredanne/pylibrabbitmq/blob/master/setup.py#L27), passing the `--with-rabbitmq` flag to setup.py ought to work as well.