# Passing compiler flags to a python package install

Tags: python, gcc, heroku

I am trying to install [this package](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy) on a system where I must install libsnappy-dev in a nonstandard location, and don't know how to include the right flags in the automatic installation to help gcc find the dev files.

Predictably, when I attempt to install from github with

```
pip git+git://github.com/andrix/python-snappy
```

I get a compiling error because the .h files (in a nonstandard place) can't be found.

```
Running setup.py install for python-snappy
building '_snappy' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappymodule.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
snappymodule.cc:31:22: error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
snappymodule.cc:77: error: ‘snappy_status’ was not declared in this scope
snappymodule.cc:78: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
snappymodule.cc:45: warning: ‘_state’ defined but not used
snappymodule.cc:56: warning: ‘SnappyCompressError’ defined but not used
snappymodule.cc:57: warning: ‘SnappyUncompressError’ defined but not used
snappymodule.cc:58: warning: ‘SnappyInvalidCompressedInputError’ defined but not used
snappymodule.cc:59: warning: ‘SnappyCompressedLengthError’ defined but not used
snappymodule.cc:77: warning: ‘snappy_strerror’ defined but not used
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u41994/python-snappy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3otpv5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
```

I am just a hacker with building software, but I think I need to set the LDFLAGS variable like so:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/lib -L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include"
```

However, that is not making it into the gcc invocation as listed above.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

***EDIT***: Progress.  Forking snappy and changing

```
snappymodule = Extension('_snappy',
                     libraries=['snappy'],
                     sources=['snappymodule.cc', 'crc32c.c'])
```

to

```
snappymodule = Extension('_snappy',
                     libraries=['snappy'],
                     sources=['snappymodule.cc', 'crc32c.c'],
                     extra_compile_args=['-L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/lib -L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include', 
                     '-I/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/lib -I/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include'])
```

has progressed the error to

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c snappymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/snappymodule.o -L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/lib -L/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include -I/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/lib -I/app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include
```

meaning we can at least pass flags in.  Still trying to figure out what the right flags are.  Manual checking still confirms that snappy.h is around.

```
~/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include $ pwd
  /app/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include
~/vendor/snappy/usr/local/include $ ls
  snappy-c.h  snappy.h  snappy-sinksource.h  snappy-stubs-public.h
```

Comment: instead of `LD_FLAGS`, try `CC_FLAGS` instead.

Comment: No dice.  Trying to fork and add compile args per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676384/how-to-pass-flag-to-gcc-in-python-setup-py-script

Comment: Right answer: export -L and -I calls for CCFLAGS, CFLAGS, and LDFLAGS to kill the problem with force.